# How to compute code with Third Party packages in Flutter (Dio and path_provider)

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app I have a section where users can download a list of images and save them to the device. For the download basicly I'm using the following code:

```
String imagePath = file["image"];
var appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String savePath = appDocDir.path + "/$uniqueID.jpg";
await Dio().download(imagePath, savePath);
await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(savePath);
```

The problem: This process freezes my UI.

I tried to write parts of it into a `compute` to isolate the process. But on `await getTemporaryDirectory()` and `await Dio().download(imagePath, savePath);` the isolated function hangs. I think that we cannot use Third Party packages on isolated environment.

Do you have an idea what could I do to isolate this parts of code?

**EDIT**
This is the entire loop:

```
await Future.forEach(files, (file) async {
  entriesController.downloadIndex.value++;
  if (file["video"] != null && file["video"].isNotEmpty) {
    String videoPath = file["video"];

    var appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String savePath = appDocDir.path + "/$uniqueID.mp4";
    await Dio().download(videoPath, savePath);
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(savePath);
  }
  if (file["video"] == null || file["video"].isEmpty) {
    String imagePath = file["image"];
    var appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String savePath = appDocDir.path + "/$uniqueID.jpg";
    try {
      await Dio().download(
        imagePath,
        savePath,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(savePath);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the code showing how you use your function? UI shouldn't be frozen on any async calls

Comment: How you are downloading multiple files, using any loop? please share function, so that it helps better to understand, Thanks

Comment: Hi @MohanSaiManthri, I've edited my topic with the entire loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this package, [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate), it allows third party package in isolate:

```
import 'package:flutter_startup/flutter_startup.dart';
import 'package:flutter_isolate/flutter_isolate.dart';

void isolate2(String arg) {
  FlutterStartup.startupReason.then((reason){
    print("Isolate2 $reason");
  });
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1),(timer)=>print("Timer Running From Isolate 2"));
}

void isolate1(String arg) async  {

  final isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(isolate2, "hello2");

  FlutterStartup.startupReason.then((reason){
    print("Isolate1 $reason");
  });
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1),(timer)=>print("Timer Running From Isolate 1"));
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(isolate1, "hello");
  Timer(Duration(seconds:5), (){print("Pausing Isolate 1");isolate.pause();});
  Timer(Duration(seconds:10),(){print("Resuming Isolate 1");isolate.resume();});
  Timer(Duration(seconds:20),(){print("Killing Isolate 1");isolate.kill();});

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```